# read a []byte from first CRLF till the end

Tags: go

in golang, having a `[]byte` (resulting from `ioutil.ReadAll`), i should need to read from the first newline CRLF until the end of the block.

could you point me some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be done easily using the [`bytes.Index`](https://godoc.org/bytes#Index) function, which returns the index of a given sub-slice of bytes in another byte slice:

```
func afterCRLF(data []byte) []byte {
    crlf := []byte("\r\n")
    index := bytes.Index(data, crlf)
    if index == -1 {
        return nil
    }
    return data[index+len(crlf):]
}
```

Note: the above function does not include the first CRLF in the returned byte slice. Remove `+len(crlf)` if you need those two characters included.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/WdylrkPwU_